# Passing Delphi 2D dynamic array to C DLL

Tags: matlab, delphi, dll, pass-by-reference

I am trying to use a DLL written in C, wrapping a Matlab DLL.

The function is defined in C as:

```
int wmlfLevel1(double* input2D, int size, char* message, double** output2d)
```

and my Delphi function is defined as:

```
func: function (input2d: pDouble; size: integer; messag: PAnsiChar; output2d: ppDouble): integer; cdecl;
```

I have defined these types to pass a matrix to the DLL:

```
type
  TDynArrayOfDouble = array of double;    
type
  T2DDynArrayOfDouble = array of TDynArrayOfDouble;    
type
  ppDouble = ^pDouble;
```

and am calling the DLL function like this:

```
var
  in2d: T2DDynArrayOfDouble;
  size: integer;
  msg: PAnsiChar;
  out2d: T2DDynArrayOfDouble;
begin
  size:= 3;
  SetLength(in2d, size, size);
  SetLength(out2d, size, size);
  in2d[0][0]:= 1; ... // init matrix values
  func(pDouble(in2d), size, msg, ppdouble(out2d));
```

The problem is the output matrix contains a huge amount of incorrect values (should contains the input matrix multiplied by 2).

What have I missed?

I can successfully call this DLL function using a static array with the following code:

```
type
  T2DArrayOfDouble = array [0..2, 0..2] of double;
type
  pT2DArrayOfDouble = ^T2DArrayOfDouble;
type
  ppT2DArrayOfDouble = ^pT2DArrayOfDouble;

func: function (input2d: pT2DArrayOfDouble; size: integer; messag: PAnsiChar; output2d: ppT2DArrayOfDouble): integer; cdecl;
...
var
  in2d: T2DArrayOfDouble;
  size: integer;
  msg: PAnsiChar;
  out2d: pT2DArrayOfDouble;
begin
  size:= High(in2d) + 1;
  in2d[0][0]:= 1; ... // init matrix values
  func(@in2d, size, msg, @out2d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double* input2D
```

That's a pointer to an array of double. But you pass it

```
in2d: T2DArrayOfDouble
```

which is a pointer to an array of pointer to array of double.

In other words you are passing `double**` to a parameter that expects `double*`.

Solve the problem by changing

```
in2d: T2DArrayOfDouble
```

to

```
in2d: TDynArrayOfDouble
```

Obviously you'll have to change the `SetLength` to match, and the code that populated the array. Although one wonders if there isn't a deeper problem given that the argument name suggests that, contrary to the type, it is a two dimensional array.

Comment: I have made the change and still get erroneous data in my output matrix except now i get correct values for the first part: `((2, 4, 6, 8.5621885079e-306, 1.2731974747e-313, 0, 0, 0,....` corresponding to Input array with 1,2,3 values.

Comment: Given the information presented to us, I think that my answer is accurate. I suggest that you do some debugging. Do some logging inside the C code.

Comment: But your right, the input is a 2 dimensional array, find below working C code for the same DLL function call:

Comment: `typedef int ( *h_w_mlfun) (double* data, int size, char *message, double*  output2d);

int main(void) {
    
    double data[][3]={ {1, 2, 3}, {6, 6, 6}, {3, 2, 1}};
    int i, j;
    char *message="String from level3.c";
    double *output2d=NULL;
    
    int resultofMfun=FALSE;
    int retval = EXIT_FAILURE;
    
    /* Handles to wrapper M functions */
    h_w_mlfun wh_fun;
    h_w_mlterm wh_term;
    
    HINSTANCE hdll;
    

        
        /* Call this function with the expected input arguments */
        resultofMfun=(wh_fun)(data, 3, message, &output2d);`

Comment: OK, `double*` is appropriate there, but you cannot use a 2D array in Delphi. That maps to `double**`. Do you understand pointers, double pointers, and how that data is laid out in memory? Part of the problem here is that the question is missing all the important information. I should probably delete this answer and leave it. I feel like I've expended my time answering the wrong question.

Comment: No thanks. I don't want to debug your problem in comments to the answer. You absolutely can debug the C code. You can add logging. I suggest that you face up to needing to do some debugging. It will do you good to learn how.

Comment: I know about pointers but not difference between memory layout of a 2D static array and a dynamic one cause my code is working with a 2D static array.

Comment: It's really very simple. My answer is correct. You need to pass a pointer to a double. So `pDouble(in2d)` where `in2d` is of type `TDynArrayOfDouble`. Then you just need to initialise that one dimensional array correctly, row major one presumes. But if you are not prepared to put the effort in to understand memory layout and debug your own program, I won't debug it for you.